# How to use intent.setComponent in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How to write the bellow code using setComponent in Kotlin.I am new to kotlin where Can I start kotlin android by using Kotlin.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings$TestingSettingsActivity"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **property reference** :-

```
intent.component = ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings$TestingSettingsActivity")
```